# PyRun_StringFlags is slow

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python C extension, and I need to convert some string into Python object, such as str `"(1001,1.0,1)"` to list `(1001,1.0,1)`.

Now I'm using `PyRun_StringFlags` function to get `py_object`, but I found this is not fast enough for me, is there any other way to do so?

Comment: (1001,1.0,1) this is a tuple, not a list. Do you mean a tuple?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're looking for Python code or C code. If it's the former, how about using `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque yes, it's tuple. but not only tuple that I want to convert, such as '{'1001':(1,2,3),}', I want change str to a pyobject.

Comment: @Kevin, I'm looking of c code